# Intuition behind Hensel's Lemma

Tags: analysis, polynomials, p-adic-number-theory

In an Elliptic Curves course, my lecturer states Hensel's Lemma as the following:

> Let $k$ is a field that is complete with respect to a non-archimedian norm $|.|$ and $$R=\{x \in k : |x| \leq 1\}$$ a subring, then for any $f(x)\in R[x]$ and any $t_0 \in R$ such that $|f(t_0)|<|f'(t_0)|^2$ there exists $t\in R$ such that $f(t)=0$ and $|t-t_0|<|f'(t_0)|$.

He then says that, intuitively speaking,

> Hensel's Lemma says that if a polynomial $f \in \mathbb Z_p[x]$ ($p$-adic integers) has a root in its reduction modulo $p$  (+ some other conditions), then it has a root in $\mathbb Q_p$.

My question is **why this intuition holds**.

I can see that it holds for simple quadratics like $f(x)=x^2-d$, where $d \in \mathbb Z$: Here if $t_0$ is a root of this modulo $p$ then, treating $t_0$ as an integer, we have $t_0^2 \equiv d \pmod p$ and so $|f(t_0)|_p=|t_0^2-d|_p<1$ but on the other hand $|f'(t_0)|_p=|2t_0|_p$ so provided $p \neq 2$ and $p$ does not divide $t_0$, we have $|f'(t_0)|_p^2=1>|f(t_0)|_p$ so the Lemma holds and there exists a root $t$ of $f$ in $\mathbb Z_p$.

I cannot, however, see how to do this with more general polynomials, and any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hensel's lemma is Newton's method in the space of p-adic numbers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel.27s_Lemma_for_p-adic_Numbers.

Comment: The above comment of @lhf hits the nail on the head. But I feel morally compelled to say that you’ve been told the *weak* form of Hensel. The good strong form says, roughly, that a factorization downstairs over the residue field induces a factorization upstairs over the original ring. There are cautions, because you need the factorization downstairs to have relatively prime factors. And the result is just a bit stronger than that, too. But I recommend this form strongly. It’s Th. 6.1.2 on P 188 of Gouvêa.

Comment: @Lubin Hensel's lemma for lifting factorizations doesn't need the factorization downstairs to have relatively prime parts, just as the root-finding Hensel's lemma doesn't need a simple root in the residue field. The root-finding Hensel's lemma in the OP uses the condition $|f(t_0)|<|f'(t_0)|^2$ to be applicable in settings where a root isn't simple in the residue field, and there's a similar version for factorizations: $|f-g_0h_0|<|R(g_0,h_0)|^2$, where $R$ is the resultant. If $g_0(x) = x-t_0$ and $h_0(x) = (f(x)-f(t_0))/(x-t_0)$, then the inequality with $R$ becomes $|f(t_0)| < |f'(t_0)|^2$.

Comment: Nice, @KCd. I was not aware of this improvement.

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity consider only the case of a polynomial $f(x)\in\mathbb{Z_p}[x]$ with a simple root $\alpha$ modulo $p$, that is $f(\alpha)=0\pmod p$ but $f'(\alpha)\neq 0\pmod p$. Now the conditions of the lemma are verified and the conclusion is that there exists $a\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $a\equiv \alpha\pmod p$ and $f(a)=0$.

For example take $f(x)=x^3+7x^2+13$. Since $f(1)\equiv 0\pmod 7$ and $f'(1)\equiv 3\pmod 7$ we immediately know that $f$ has a root in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ which is of the form $1+7a$, $a\in \mathbb{Z}_7$.